# zlib not found but it already installed

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmake

I've installed zlib library but when I am compiling this project - https://github.com/mgbellemare/Arcade-Learning-Environment - 
it gives me an error not found zlib.

When I run

```
gcc -o a a.c  ; ./a
```

where `a.c` file uses "#include "

I've tried these flags

```
-DZLIB_LIBRARY:FILEPATH 
-DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH
-ZLIB_CFLAGS=" " ZLIB_LIBS="-lz"
-lz
```

and recompile the cmake package from source

```
/home/mostafa/Documents/temp/Arcade-Learning-Environment/src/common/ScreenExporter.cpp:18:10: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <zlib.h>
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ale-bin.dir/build.make:183: CMakeFiles/ale-bin.dir/src/common/ScreenExporter.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:100: CMakeFiles/ale-bin.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

Comment: You need to install the zlib development packages.

Comment: The project doesn't use `find_library(zlib)` for locate zlib library, so attempts to set `ZLIB_*` variable are waste. It seems the project expects `zlib` to be installed into system-wide place, so `#include <zlib.h>` and `-lz` will be work without additional settings. You may try to pass additional include directories via `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable. E.g. find this variable in `CMakeCache.txt` file (located in the build directory), and add `-I<your-zlib-include-directory>` option into it.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, I had to create a new user and things worked